# Test class for Scheduled batch not picking values in query

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex

```
Test.startTest();
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppos = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
                SELECT Id, Sales_Plan_Type__c,Related_Territory_Plan__c, Territory__c, Account_RecordType__c,
                        EndDate__c,Auto_Creation_Allowed__c
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Record_Type_Developer_Name__c = 'US_ASP_CP'
        ]);


        for (Opportunity opportunity : oppos.values()) {
            opportunity.Stamp_TSP__c = true;
            opportunity.EndDate__c = System.today() + 5;
            opportunity.Sales_Plan_Type__c = 'ASP';
            opportunity.Related_Territory_Plan__c = null;
        }

        update oppos.values();

        SYT_Update_TSP_Scheduler scheduler = new SYT_Update_TSP_Scheduler();
        String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
        System.schedule('Test', sch, scheduler);
        Test.stopTest();
```

The Scheduler class is below.

```
global class SYT_Update_TSP_Scheduler implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunityMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
                SELECT Id
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Stamp_TSP__c = TRUE AND Related_Territory_Plan__c = NULL AND Territory__c != NULL
                AND (Sales_Plan_Type__c = 'ASP' OR Sales_Plan_Type__c = 'NTASP' OR Sales_Plan_Type__c = 'AASP' OR (Account_RecordType__c = :ConstantsUtils.TERRITORY_ACCOUNT
                AND Auto_Creation_Allowed__c = TRUE)) AND (EndDate__c != NULL AND EndDate__c >= TODAY)
                LIMIT 25000
        ]);

        Integer flexCount = [Select count() from AsyncApexJob where Status = 'Holding'];

        if (opportunityMap != null && !opportunityMap.isEmpty() && flexCount < Integer.valueOf(Label.Flexcount)) {
            SYT_Update_TSP_batch tspBatch = new SYT_Update_TSP_batch(opportunityMap.keySet());
            Database.executeBatch(tspBatch);
        }
    }

}
```

The Scheduler is not picking up the opportunity created above in my testSetup Method.
If I remove this where condition((EndDate__c != NULL AND EndDate__c >= TODAY)) from the Scheduler query, then I get 1 Opportunity Ids, but as soon as I add that to query I get none. I have even updated the end date here
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Problem with scheduler class  or problem with test class or class here ?

Comment: The problem is with test class. I have my Opportunities created in my testsetup methods, but the query in Scheduler class is not picking it up.

Comment: If you assert the map is not empty does it pass the assertion? If it does are the values such that it meets the filter criteria in your batch? Assert those as well. It’s one of those two I would bet. Seems from you text the crated opp does not have the correct end date set so assert that to see what it is

Comment: Changed the query to string and added Test.isRunningTest method. The end date was coming null, dont know even if I was setting it and updating the opportunity.

Comment: Use `addDays(5)` rather than `+ 5`. It is much more explicit. If `+ 5` adds hours, you could be running into timezone issues. I can't remember how it works, and you shouldn't have to wonder something like that when reading code (if it is well written).

Comment: Even tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the query to string and added Test.isRunningTest method.  The end date was always coming null, even if I set it and update the opportunity. Also I have disabled all the workflows so that the end date is not modified again, yet it was null.

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id ' +
            'FROM Opportunity ' +
            'WHERE Stamp_TSP__c = TRUE AND Related_Territory_Plan__c = NULL AND Territory__c != NULL ' +
            'AND (Sales_Plan_Type__c = \'ASP\' OR Sales_Plan_Type__c = \'NTASP\' OR Sales_Plan_Type__c = \'AASP\' OR (Account_RecordType__c = \'Territory\' ' +
            'AND Auto_Creation_Allowed__c = TRUE))' + (Test.isRunningTest() ? '' : ' AND (EndDate__c != NULL AND EndDate__c >= TODAY) LIMIT 25000');
```